# Change the default for Excel upload

Tags: acumatica

I have custom screens where I've used the functionality of uploading an excel sheet into a grid.  The default dropdown is 'Update Existing'.  What I would like to know is if there is a way to change the default to 'Insert All Records' from the dropdown.  Shown below is an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: If you are not passing in the key values in the import, running "Update Existing" should do the insert all records for you because it will not find the keys to update.

Comment: That doesn't work for us.  We need to default to 'Insert All Records', if that's possible.

Comment: If you are not inserting the same key values the update existing should work the same way? can you describe how update existing is working different than insert all records? Also might be good to post the idea to the Acumatica feedback for easier configuration (if at all possible): https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas